# Search Engine friendly urls php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

So i have been try to figure out how to make my link search engine friendly and i have learned so far that the .htaccess file has to be in the root directory of the website Folder. The following is the contents of the folder which i think it has an error because it keeps getting hidden from the wamp server

```
RewriteEngine On

Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^(([a-zA-Z0-9])*\/([a-zA-Z0-9])*)*$ $1.php?article=$2
```

Now i am trying to do the following.

Turn this link :`http://localhost:63342/EuroSkills/View/Beer.php?article=6`
Into this link `http://localhost:63342/EuroSkills/View/Beer6`

What i am changing is that **beer.php** file into just **beer**

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Its not even showing on my wamp server the website and when i remove the contents of the the .htaccess it shows. Also how to  change the links that i showed.

Comment: I see three sets of parentheses. Are you sure that $1 and $2 are the matches you want?

Comment: I am not sure what they mean because i found the code on the internet and changed it to the one i tough is good for my links.

Comment: There are so many tutorials on this on the web

Comment: I did search for them yes and i learned a lot but what i cant figure out is for me link i cant figure out how to do it,

Answer (score 0):

Place code in your `/EuroSkills/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /EuroSkills/View/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?article=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Give me a sec to try it out!

Comment: Okay so i am haveing this problem when i am puting in that code the folder doesnt show any more here is an example with before and after. Before: http://imgur.com/8ZgT4IH and after i put the code this is what happens http://imgur.com/teBhGuq

Comment: What URL did you enter in your browser and what is location of this .htaccess? Does `/EuroSkills/` also have .htaccess file?

Comment: EuroSkills is the one that has the .htaccess file i also have some code in the .htacces like <files index>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</files> which works ok

Comment: Also i put it in the root and when i put the rewrite it gives me internal server error

Comment: Check updated rule now. If it doesn't work then post your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: No i have fixed it i had a module disabled on my server. now that is fixed i am putting in the link http://localhost/EuroSkills/View/Beer6 and gives me an 404 error meaning page not found.

Comment: Sorry what is fixed and what is not working? As I suggested post your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: Based on your other question I edited it again. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

They way I handled URLs in an old PHP application I had, is to map **ALL** urls to index.php. Then use PHP code to parse out $_REQUEST the path that was requested, and make the decisions there.